# how to prevent re-render if fetch from many sources in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using `react hooks` in React Native.
My problem is that the function of `useState` which to initialize state makes re-render.
So if I set state like below

```js
    const [A, setA] = useState(false);
    const [B, setB] = useState(false);
    const [C, setA] = useState(false);

    // ...

    const testFunc = () => {
        setA(true);
        setB(true);
        setC(true);
    }
```

---

**EDITED**
I think examples were wrong.
Here's another example.

```js
const useFetch(coords) {
    const [example, setExample] = useState([])
    const [checker, setChecker] = useState(false);

    const fetchData = () => {
        axios.fetch(`url+${coords.latitue}+${coords.longitude}`).then(){
            setExample(res.data());
            setChecker(true);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [coords])

    return example;
}

const useLocation = () => {
    ...
    return coords;
}

const App = () => {
    const coords = useLocation();
    const example = useFetch(coords); // example is undefined.
    const [data, setData] = useState(example); // data is undefined.
}
```

---

It causes many re-render as many as I use the set function.
Is this natural thing?
If I don't want to make this re-render, can't use the set function multiple times?

Comment: Where is the fetch? you mean something like promise all?

Comment: @Omer Thank you for your reply. My example was not good enough to explain my question.
So, I added an example to show you.

Comment: if coords frequently changes, then yes. it will always re-render using the updated lat, long.

Comment: @JosephD. Thank you for your reply. Do you mean if I fetch data from many sources, then `view` would be rendered many times as I used `setFunction` of `useState`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do it in straightforward way. I will suggest you the two solutions for it.

**Solution 1:** Combine states in one object.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({A: false, B: false, C: false});

// ...

const testFunc = () => {
    setValue({A: true, B: true, C: true});
}
```

**Solution 2:** Another solution is `useReducer`.

```
const [state, setState] = useReducer(
  (state, newState) => ({...state, ...newState}),
  {A: false, B: false, C: false}
);

// ...

const testFunc = () => {
    setState({A: true, B: true, C: true});
}
```

Here I have implemented your another example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-usestate-wcjshg

Hope this will help for you!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My example was not good enough to explain my question.
So, I added an example to show you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.
I think my example wasn't enough to explain my problem.
I'd like to set state sequentially cause each of custom hooks is related.
For example, `B custom hook` need the data from `A custom hook` to fetch data.

Comment: It's straightforward example and I am using same in my one of the project. This should be work for you.

Comment: I added another example to explain my issue. Would this work for my second example?

Comment: just to mention: with destructuring it would look same way readable as having multiple `useState`: `const [{A, B, C}, setState] = useReducer(...)`

Comment: @MingyuJeon I have integrated your example in code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-usestate-wcjshg Can you please look into it and let me know is it working for you?

Comment: @ClueMediator It's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @ClueMediator Btw, why too many render happens here? Is this because I set state a lot?

Comment: I think these 2 solution is the same: merging state.

Answer (score 2):

React does not batch state updates if they are triggered outside React-based event. That means, if you want your state updates to be batched you need to wrap it on an event handle such as `onClick`.

If your local component state is non-trival and/or using an event handler is not an option, I'd recommend you to use `useReducer` as you can batch your state updates within that.

> This appears to be normal React behavior. It works the exact same way if you were to call setState() in a class component multiple times.
>
> React currently will batch state updates if they're triggered from within a React-based event, like a button click or input change. It will not batch updates if they're triggered outside of a React event handler, like a setTimeout().
>
> I think there's plans long-term to always batch events, but not sure on the details

Sources:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259#issuecomment-439632622
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259#issuecomment-468937068

Comment: This is not always true. Try fetching data inside an onClick event and using the set function of `useState` and it will cause re-renders for as many set functions you use.
E.G:
`const res = await fetch('your-api');
      setFlag(true); setResult(true); setOpen(true);`
this code will cause 3 re-renders.

Comment: The same thing happened to me, I realized that if I use fetch within the eventhandler, the useStates are rendered individually (consecutively), but if I remove the fetch, the rendering is only one (batch)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the other answers, React does not batch state updates if they are triggered outside React-based events (in `then` for example), one of the solutions is to merge your state in one object and call setState one time. But if you like to keep your state separated, the solution is to use `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates` like this :

```js
    const fetchData = () => {
        axios.fetch(`url+${coords.latitue}+${coords.longitude}`).then(() => {
            ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
                setExample(res.data());
                setChecker(true);
            });
        });
    }
```

Recommended by Dan Abramov [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259#issuecomment-439702367)

Comment: This is true & should have more upvotes.